# Undeclared Scope (Switch Statement in Arduino)

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am having troubles with programming a line tracking robot (with motors and using the Arduino Uno) and using a switch statement to declare the different movements for the motors.
So far, I have:

```
void loop() {
int sensorValueright = analogRead(A0);
int sensorValuecentre = analogRead(A1);
int sensorValueleft = analogRead(A2);

switch (direction1) {
    case "right":
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH); //Establishes forward direction of Channel A
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel A
  analogWrite(3, 60);   //Motor A at quarter speed

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //Establishes forward direction of Channel B
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel B
  analogWrite(11, 125);   //Motor B at half speed
  delay(1000);
  break;

  case "centre":
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH); //Forward A
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel A
  analogWrite(3, 100);   //Motor A = Motor B speed

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //Forward B
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel B
  analogWrite(11, 100);  //Motor A = Motor B speed
  delay(500);
  break;

  case "left":
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH); //Establishes forward direction of Channel A
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel A
  analogWrite(3, 125);   //Motor A at Half Speed

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //Establishes forward direction of Channel B
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel B
  analogWrite(11, 60);   //Motor B at Quarter Speed
  delay(1000);
  break;

  }

  if (sensorValuecentre < 1){
    direction1 == "centre"
  }

  else if (sensorValueright < 1){
    direction1 == "right"
  }

  else if (sensorValueleft < 1){
    direction1 == "left"
  }

  else{
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH); //Establishes forward direction of Channel A
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel A
  analogWrite(3, 50);   //Motor A at low speed

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //Establishes forward direction of Channel B
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel B
  analogWrite(11, 50);   //Motor B at low speed
  delay(500);
  }

  delay(1);
}
```

But I am getting the following error while compiling:

```
line_tracker_test_switch.ino: In function 'void loop()':
line_tracker_test_switch.ino:20:9: error: 'direction1' was not declared in this scope
line_tracker_test_switch.ino:60:3: error: expected ';' before '}' token
line_tracker_test_switch.ino:64:3: error: expected ';' before '}' token
line_tracker_test_switch.ino:68:3: error: expected ';' before '}' token
Error compiling.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see no declaration of direction1. Do you?

Comment: Read the error - `direction1` isn't declared, nor have you shown is how/where it is declared!

Comment: Also, `direction1 == "right"` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: And you're missing a bunch of semicolons at the indicated places.

Comment: Are you sure that the [Arduino language](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage) allows you to use strings in `switch` statements?  C does not allow that.  The referenced manual doesn't say either way directly (at least, not under `switch case`).  I suspect it won't be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"direction1" has not been declared anywhere in the code you pasted.
Somewhere there needs to be a line of the form
`type direction1;` for example `char *direction1;` or `int direction1;`
to tell the compiler what direction1 is.

The other 3 errors indicate those lines are missing semicolons at the end.
`direction1 == "left";` This is also unlikely to be what you want. `==` is the equality operator. `=` is the assignment operator. This is also a strange way to use these operators because strings work differently from primitive types such as `int` and `float`. You cannot compare or assign them directly. You will be accessing the pointer value instead.

Using strings with switch statements is not allowed in standard C.

Create integer constants instead
`enum {LEFT, RIGHT, CENTRE};` and replace "left" with LEFT and so on.